# Export/serialize case classes to json

Tags: playframework, akka

I am using akka with play framework and I feel it's quite cumbersome to serialize/deserialize jsons. Play framework requires me to define writers/readers from/to JSON. In my project I am using huge json objects that may change and I want to make it simpler. Is there a way to provide some default writers/readers from case classes?

I know this functionality is provided by lift-json (extract,decompose methods), however then I need to convert it from/to Play JSON for every single request/response. Is there such functionality in Play JSON?

Answer (score 0):

It seems complicated at first but it's actually straightforward.  Scala is strong typing and the dynamic nature of JSON with dynamic languages like JavaScript or Ruby makes it somewhat annoying to start with, but you will start to appreciate the benefits of strong typing.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Animal(name: String, age: Int)
implicit val formatAnimal = Json.format[Animal]
```

That is all you need.  Then, to parse:

```
val animal: Animal = Json.parse("""{"name":"Bob","age":5}""").as[Animal]
```

and to stringify:

```
val json: String = Json.toJson(animal)
```

You can also use `JsPath` to parse something nested in the JSON, for example:

```
(jspath / "data" / "result").as[Animal]
```

The framework comes with formats built in for `String`, `Long`, and so on, if you want to use a different case class such as `Animal`, you'd need to create a format for it like I did above.

Comment: hello and thanks for the answer. I am mainly concerned with the line "implicit val formatAnimal = Json.format[Animal]", because my objects are quite huge and I'd rather use some default formatter to/from case classes. In other words, I'd like that formatter to by selected by default.

Comment: "I'd like that formatter to by selected by default" <- can you rephrase that? I don't understand sorry.

Comment: the thing is, that I have objects that have nested objects and they have nested objects... and so on...  I don't want to have 30 lines that just defines implicit formatter for every case class within json. What I'd like to have is something like json.as[HugeObject] and have it parsed into HugeObject. Or are these 30 lines not needed anymore and is it enough to register implicit formatter for the top-level object only?

Comment: The case classes don't have to be exhaustive, they can contain *only* the fields that you want to read and/or write. For example, if you want just the name from HugeObject, then `case class HugeObject(name: String)`.  If it's deeply nested, you can use JsPath like I explained.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. My question is: Will this work if Animal would contain another object inside? For example Animal(owner: Person). Or will I need to register implicit formatter for Person also?

Comment: it does not work by default. I get an exception "No implicit format for Person available". Because I have a lot of case classes, I will need to define a lot of cumbersome code for every single one

Comment: You can write a script to search for all case classes, and create corresponding `implicit val formatPerson = Json.format[Person]` implicits. How can it get any easier than this apart form being dynamic with no typing like in JavaScript?

Comment: json4s is simpler. You will just specify the top-level case class and it will get parsed properly. Spray provides an extension for the httpx module and I have it working now

Comment: Play allows you to just specify the top-level case class too. You only need the nested case classes if you want to be able to access them too.